# Different SQL query plans with Select TOP (n)

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to view the query plan of a simple select Top (n). Every time i changed n (the number of records i am getting) the query plan changes, with Select Top 10 specifically causing performance issues, with less than 10 or greater than 10 the query runs smoothly.

The query is generated by Entity Framework (4.2) if it makes a difference.

The query is :

```
 exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (10) 
[Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project1].[DateReceived] AS [DateReceived], 
[Project1].[Status] AS [Status], 
[Project1].[Subject] AS [Subject], 
[Project1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Project1].[Path] AS [Path], 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[C2] AS [C2], 
[Project1].[C3] AS [C3],
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

WHERE [Project1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Project1].[DateReceived] DESC',N'@p__linq__0 int,@p__linq__1 int,@p__linq__2 datetime2(7),@p__linq__3 datetime2(7),@p__linq__4 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__5 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__6 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__7 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=-1,@p__linq__1=-1,@p__linq__2='2013-03-15 00:00:00',@p__linq__3='2013-04-15 23:59:55',@p__linq__4=N'ALL',@p__linq__5=N'ALL',@p__linq__6=N'',@p__linq__7=N'%%'
```

Why the TOP 10 specifically is causing performance issues?

I cannot share images yet, here is the links:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/407/top10a.png/

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/580/top20x.png/

Comment: What is your **Question**?

Comment: Could you post the execution plans too? It would be pretty helpful.
My first idea:
SQL Server changes it's executions plans using it's statistics. You may assume update statistics.

Comment: Execution plan added to my question above.

Comment: @NEO1540: Publish these execution plans as XML on http://pastebin.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JanDrozen said, its most likely a statistics problem. When the size of the data goes over a certain threshold, the generated execution plan is no longer the best plan, but the statistics aren't allowing it to get the correct estimated number of rows. The optimizer doesn't always generate the best execution plan. It is an impressive feat of programming achievement, often making gold from our chaff, but it can really only do the best it can, with the data that it has on hand. It uses carnality statistics and will use the estimated result set sizes to determine what it thinks is the best plan.

One way to tell if it is a stats issue without trying to update the stats first, would be to enable the actual execution plan, and look that the properties.

Check that:

- Where the data is coming into the pipeline, that the estimated number of rows is close to the actual number of rows.
- That the properties of the execution plan say that the optimizer arrived at an optimal plan. In the properties, it will tell you why it chose the plan. Sometimes, if the stats are way out of date, the optimizer never finds an optimal plan, and just has to use the best it could find.

This query is an example to update stats in the example adventureworks database.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
UPDATE STATISTICS Production.Product(Products)
    WITH FULLSCAN, NORECOMPUTE;
GO
```

There is a stored procedure `sp_updatestats [ [ @resample = ] 'resample']`
but I have never had great results with it and I could never force it to update with a full scan, which is in my experience the best way to get good statistics.

If you need to do this for a large number of tables, here is a script I've used before to regenerate stats using dynamic sql.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX);
SELECT @sql = (SELECT 'UPDATE STATISTICS ' +
                  quotename(s.name) + '.' + quotename(o.name) +
                  ' WITH FULLSCAN; ' AS [text()]
           FROM   sys.objects o
           JOIN   sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
           WHERE  o.type = 'U'
           FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)');
PRINT @sql
EXEC (@sql)
```

[Here](http://blog.idera.com/sql-server/understanding-sql-server-statistics/) is a good article on statistics and gives a good breakdown on what they are, what they do, and how to look at them.